# How to make a horizontal scrollable view?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view containing a linear layout.
Something like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/product_hsv"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_container_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

> What I want to do is to add n number of the same layout to display
>   product collection in a Horizontal scroll view.

The picture below will give you an idea of what I have done so far.

[image: Expected output]

For this, I have added product collection view to `R.id.product_container_layout`.

```
String[] productCollectionArr = new String[]{"Shirt", "Jewellary", "Moto X Play", "Ellis Flat"};

for (int i = 0; i < productCollectionArr.length; i++) {
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.product_container_layout);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_product, null);//child.xml
    parentLayout.addView(child);
}

for (int i = 0; i < productCollectionArr.length; i++) {
    LinearLayout eachProductLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.product_container_layout);
    ((TextView) eachProductLayout.findViewById(R.id.product_name_tv)).setText(productCollectionArr[i]);
}
```

But **the problem is passing values. Since each view added to product_container_layout has the same ids. Therefore only first element gets the value from the product collection array.**

What I can do is generate view id for each view and its element and map these ids to certain name so that I could access them by id.

Is this the correct methodology or should I do something else?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to populate your view before adding to container or save links to all items. It will looks like this:

```
    LinearLayout parentLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i ++) {
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);//child.xml
((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(items.get(i).getName(); // where R.id.name is a textView in your child.xml layout.
    parentLayout.addView(child);
}
```

after all, you can access to your elements by index, if you want to change it:

```
parentLayout.getChildAt(index)
```

But if you have a lot of items, it's not good idea. In this case you will not recycle your views and will consume a lot of memory.
I suggest to use [recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) from support library.

Comment: @Shubham if it helps, mark question as solution, please

Comment: You can use Recycler view and make teh orientation as horizontal in Layout manager.

Comment: I have marked this a solution as it exactly solves the problem. Also, you can check I have updated the problem statement and content so that it can be reproduced easily unlike previously.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to add this  first :

 <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/galleryImages"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/chim_image_view_divider"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twenty"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Images_scroller_view_linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

ImageScrollerViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Images_scroller_view_linear_layout);
        ImageScrollerViewLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

 - addImagesTo list:

void addImages() {
        ImageScrollerViewLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

        int i = 0;
        final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = 0;
        if (myImagesList != null && myImagesList.size() > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < myImagesList.size(); i++) {

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

                pixels = (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(pixels, pixels);
                params.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new SelectNewSingleImageClickListener());
                imageView.setImageResource(myImagesList.get(i));
                ImageScrollerViewLinearLayout.addView(imageView, i);

            }

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add code in xml file
<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
                    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
                    style="@style/TwoWayView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:padding="10dp" >
                </org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can use **DevSmart** library for horizontal listview which is similar to **ListView**.

    https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android
```

Comment: Am i doing in a right way. Can you please focus on the approach.

Comment: You want to add the list item at run time